# Portainer no such image error when deploying stack, but image exists

Tags: docker, portainer

When I deploy a stack(docker-compose from github) on any environment, I will get a "Error:No such image" during the deployment. This happens when portainer needs to pull the image. If the image is already present it will not throw the error.

I have confirmed these images do in fact exist on dockerhub.

I can successfully pull these images manually via the `images` tab on the respective environment.

I can run the docker-compose manually on my development machine and it works fine. If I manually delete the local images then it just re-downloads them, because they do exist.

This behavior started today. I installed portainer a few days ago and has been working fine. But, as of today, this error has started happening.

The environments are wildly different from each other, there are 3 of them, and this happens on all of them. If I ssh into the environments and manually pull the docker-compose from github, it runs just fine. This appears to be a problem with portainer.

Answer (score 0):

This was occurring because the docker-compose pull policy was set to build.

```
pull-policy: build
```

Remove the pull policy altogether from the docker-compose and you're good to go.